# How to execute an action every second in a thread?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

I know that timers are made to execute periodic actions ,but I'm not sure if timers are the best way to execute periodic action in a thread, what I'm trying to do is getting some informations from worker threads, to be clearer: there is a main thread that needs to get a property of another thread (woker), this one is variant, that's why I need to get its value every interval of time.
it's something like :

```
procedure mainThread.execute;
begin
// every second :
val := workerThread.property;
end;
```

Normally, the main thread needs to wait a second, then get the value, example:

```
procedure mainThread.execute;
begin
while (condition) do
begin
sleep(1000);
val := workerThread.property;
end;
```

But, what if the worker thread terminates, and the main thread is still waiting to get the value `sleep(1000)` , this will cause a lost time, because the main thread should immediately exit the loop when worker thread terminates. I don't want the main thread to wait if worker thread has already terminated its job ( there is no need to get that property value if the worker thread takes less than 1 seconde), that's why I shouldn't do it this way.
I also thought about using `waitformultipleobjects` withing that loop, so assuming that I have many workers:, it would rather be:

```
procedure mainThread.execute;
begin
while (condition) do
begin
waitForMultipleObjects(Threads, @Array, True, 1000);
//If elapsed Time < 1000 , this means that all threads terminated, then main thread must quit this loop
//If elapsed Time = 1000 :
val := workerThread.property;
// Calculate the new value of condition  
end;
```

So,what I want to achieve is:  the main thread must exit the loop only if:

- all worker threads terminated (immediately after they terminate): while main thread is waiting to get the property value, if threads terminate, the main thread exit the loop, if not, it continue waiting until elapsed time =  1 s and get the new value.
- the condition is false.
  I have no problem with setting the condition to false, because I have to calculate something each iteration and decide its new value.

I hope I was clear in my explanation.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: The easiest way is to call `Sleep(1000)` in a loop, doing your actions in each loop iteration.  Alternatively, use `CreateWaitableTimer()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` instead of `Sleep()`.

Comment: Why do you think timer aren't the best way?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaitForMultipleObjects` is indeed the function that you should call. Your problem  though is that you are failing to check the return value. Here's a rule of thumb for whenever you call a Windows API function:

> Always check the value returned by the function.

You will avoid a lot of problems if you follow that rule.

In this case the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) says that, when passing `True` for `bWaitAll`:

- A return value of **WAIT_OBJECT_0** to (**WAIT_OBJECT_0** + nCount– 1) means that the function returned because all specified objects are signaled.
- A return value of **WAIT_TIMEOUT** means that the function returned because the specified timeout elapsed.
- A return value of **WAIT_FAILED** indicates that the call failed for some reason, and that you should call `GetLastError` to find out what that reason was.

Note that you do not need to worry about the **WAIT_ABANDONED_0** to (**WAIT_ABANDONED_0** + nCount– 1) case because you are not passing any mutex objects.